# Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: java, android

Good Day,
I'm newbie in Android. I tried to download TheAnswer project and was faced with that error below:

> ```
> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
> This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
> For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
> Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
> ```

And the output

```
-----------------------
13:10:59.705 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
13:11:00.270 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
13:11:00.333 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=fbfdb6ee-d530-4190-b211-a2e4fb725aa4,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\vadims.leonovs\.gradle\daemon,pid=6892,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
13:11:00.342 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1438078260342
13:11:00.426 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Software Loopback Interface 1
13:11:00.429 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
13:11:00.430 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.431 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
13:11:00.431 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
13:11:00.433 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Software Loopback Interface 1
13:11:00.433 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (SSTP)
13:11:00.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.437 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (SSTP)
13:11:00.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (L2TP)
13:11:00.441 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.443 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.443 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (L2TP)
13:11:00.444 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (PPTP)
13:11:00.446 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.449 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.449 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (PPTP)
13:11:00.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
13:11:00.451 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.453 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.454 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
13:11:00.454 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)
13:11:00.456 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.458 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.458 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)
13:11:00.459 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
13:11:00.461 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.463 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.463 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
13:11:00.464 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)
13:11:00.466 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)
13:11:00.469 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface RAS Async Adapter
13:11:00.471 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.473 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.474 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface RAS Async Adapter
13:11:00.475 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
13:11:00.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
13:11:00.480 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
13:11:00.482 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:e0:0:0:0%11
13:11:00.485 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
13:11:00.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /10.122.146.212
13:11:00.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:ace3:ed34:9609:491e%12
13:11:00.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
13:11:00.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
13:11:00.492 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.494 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:a7a:92d4%13
13:11:00.494 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
13:11:00.496 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.498 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.498 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:8c2f:22a5:c0df:1020%14
13:11:00.499 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
13:11:00.499 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
13:11:00.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
13:11:00.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.508 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.509 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:6543:15e3:4281:5e96%16
13:11:00.509 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
13:11:00.510 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
13:11:00.512 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.514 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.515 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.517 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.520 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.520 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.521 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.523 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.526 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.527 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.532 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.534 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.534 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.535 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.536 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.539 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.539 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.543 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.543 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.549 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.552 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.564 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.564 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.565 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.567 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.570 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.571 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.574 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.575 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.577 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.578 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.578 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.580 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.582 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.583 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.583 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.588 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.592 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.592 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.594 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.596 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.596 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.597 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.598 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.603 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.606 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.607 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.609 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.610 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.610 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.612 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.615 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.619 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Listening on [2dd41106-28f8-4395-bab9-a4ab260bd7ee port:63691, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]].
13:11:00.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon starting at: Tue Jul 28 13:11:00 EEST 2015, with address: [2dd41106-28f8-4395-bab9-a4ab260bd7ee port:63691, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
13:11:00.630 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertising the daemon address to the clients: [2dd41106-28f8-4395-bab9-a4ab260bd7ee port:63691, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
13:11:00.631 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertised daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=fbfdb6ee-d530-4190-b211-a2e4fb725aa4,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\vadims.leonovs\.gradle\daemon,pid=6892,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

I tried to look for information, but nothing helps me. Thanks a lot for everyone!

Comment: No one can tell from mere stack trace... At least show your code from where it happens

Comment: P.S. It isn't all output log, because of stackOverFlow I can`t to attach all log

Comment: @CoderNeji I tried to download TheAnswer project from [here](https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples) .After that I import this project to android studio, and after that gradle try to make his work, and this error happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
1) Delete android workspace 
2) Import second time the project 
3) Make new android workspace
4) Gradle suggest to install sdk, install that (I don`t know why)
5) It works!